# I want to change nickname of discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to change the name of a discord bot and I have read numerous tutorials and Stack Overflow posts and I still cannot get it. The code is primarily taken from open source bot code, so I know it works (something with my bot setup maybe?)

As I understand it, this code loops through each guild the bot is a member of and sets the nickname.

I found the botId by right clicking the bot in the channel and copying ID.

```js
const { guildId } = require('../config');

module.exports = (client, botId, nickname) => {
 client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    const { id } = guild;

    client.guilds.cache
    .get(id)
    .members.cache.get(botId)
    .setNickname(nickname);
  });
};
```

The bot shows up in the channel (after using oauth2 url), so I'm assuming that means they are a member of the guild.

However, when running this code the bot is not found. I've tried several things from other posts like `guild.array()` to try and see a full list of the members in the guild, but nothing has worked.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('943284788004012072');
const bot = guild.members.cache.get('956373150864642159')
if (!bot) return console.log('bot not found');
```

Here is the full bot

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const eventBus = require('../utils/events/eventBus');
const setNickname = require('../utils/setNickname');

const getPrice = require('../modules/statsGetters/getPriceDEX');

const { bots } = require('../config');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('DEX Price Watch Bot Ready');

  client.user.setPresence({
    activities: [{ name: 'DEX Price', type: 'WATCHING' }],
    status: 'online',
  });

  const price = await getPrice();
  setNickname(client, bots.priceDEX, price);

  eventBus.on(drip.update, async () => {
    const price = await getPrice();
    setNickname(client, bots.priceDEX, price); //update price in config file
  });
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_PRICE_DEX);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample of changing bot's nickname for every guild that bot joined

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => { //This is to get all guild that the bot joined  
     const nickname = args.slice(0).join(" ") //You wanted to change nickname
     guild.me.setNickname(nickname); //setting the nickname of your bot
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're doing it wrong.
Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname

I would suggest using this module code:

```js
const { guildId } = require('../config');

module.exports = (client, nickname) => {
    client.guilds.cache
    .get(guildId).me.setNickname(nickname);
};
```

And use it in this way in your main bot code: `setNickname(client, price)`

Edit:
Oh wait, I just realised you didn't use the correct intents (guild members), so you definitely need to use `guild.me` (as written above by me) or use `guild.members.fetch()` as it fetches members which aren't cached.
More info: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch